# Is there any way to disallow Sharepoint Online user profile images from being cached by browsers?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property, cache

Currently, when a user uploads a profile picture in Sharepoint Online and saves the change, the picture will get immediately uploaded into the Profile Pictures library in the MySites content database(https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx?id=%2FUser%20Photos%2FProfile%20Pictures).

However, the user won't notice any changes to their profile pictures in the top right corner of SharePoint or in Delve profiles because the old "anonymous" picture is still in their browser's image cache. The change is only noticeable when you open the user's account in an incognito tab and it will show that they've uploaded a profile picture and it shows correctly.

Is there any way to prevent user profile pictures from being saved into the image cache or force browsers to somehow check if the profile picture in SharePoint has changed?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this problem also extends to caching of Outlook and Delve profile pictures as well as SharePoint Online user profile pictures.

I have created a simple 'user profile' app in SharePoint Online that retrieves a users photo from their SharePoint user profile, as well as their name and job title.
The app also provides a link to change user profile picture via https://portal.office.com/userphoto. This portal updates and displays the profile image for Delve, Outlook and SharePoint immediately within O365.

However, the browser (IE, Edge & Chrome) cache the original profile image in my app, so I have a disparity, where the profile image in the top right hand corner of SPO has changed (and in Delve/Outlook) yet my app is displaying a cached version, undermining the entire profile picture change feature.

I've also played around with pulling user profile pictures from Delve and Outlook directly (http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/05/how-to-get-sharepoint-profile-picture/) but browser caching issue still remains.

Incognito and Private modes will load the latest profile pictures.